# Error instalación GRUB en Ubuntu 20 (arranque dual)

Tags: ubuntu, windows10, instalacion, grub

Tengo la siguiente configuración, bastante sencilla: 2 discos duros independientes, uno con Windows 10 y otro vacío en el que pretendo instalar Ubuntu 20. Sin embargo, cuando procedo a instalarlo, me da error GRUB. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que se instale correctamente?

Añado: He conseguido instalar Ubuntu. Sin embargo, a la hora de reparar el arranque con boot-repair, el programa me avisa de que debería pasar la BIOS de UEFI a Legacy. Sin embargo, por lo que he leído, si hago este cambio, Windows no arrancará

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Siempre me pasa eso cuando instalo Ubuntu después que windows. Lo que hago es descargarme el iso de [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/), hacer un usb booteable con esa imagen y seguir [estas instrucciones](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/es/). Boot repair reparará el arranque y tendrás el grup al encender tu PC para elegir entre los dos sistemas operativos.

Comment: Buenas Jaime. Pues he hecho lo que me has comentado, pero en el proceso de reparación me ha recomendado el programa pasar de arranque UEFI a Legacy. Si hago esto, por lo que he leído, no voy a tener acceso a Windows :/ Así que estoy igual que antes

Answer (score 0):

Se necesitan más datos para saber exactamente qué pasa, pero por lo que entiendo intentas instalar un OS en cada disco duro. En ese caso puedes "jugar" con el boot para elegir desde qué disco arrancar, ahora bien, esto será un poco molesto. Lo que sugiro que hagas es instalar el dual boot encima del boot en el disco de windows (el cuál será el principal) para que siempre entre el boot y pregunte el OS.

Comment: Buenas Jorge. Qué datos necesitas?